# how to trigger dropdown change event manually ? when I am selecting data from Modal?

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I have a dropdown list which is getting Accountoff data from database through ajax. Now I am selecting data from modal and giving the val to the dropdown list and triggering it change method manually. But its not working.

This is the code where I am giving the selected data from modal to dropdown list.

```
AccountOf = function (value) {
    var lblBrandCode = $(value).closest('tr').find("#hdnCusCode").val();
    var lblCusDesc = $(value).closest('tr').find('#lblCusDesc').val();
    $("#AccountOfModal").modal("hide");
    $("#ddlACof").val(lblBrandCode);

    //document.getElementById("ddlACof").value = lblBrandCode;
    $("#ddlACof").change();        
}
```

here is the the code that invoke the above method.

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/BookingOrder/Select_CustomerDetailModal")',
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.Success == true) {
                var item = JSON.parse(data.Response)
                $("#AccountOfTable tbody tr").remove()
                if (item.length > 0) {

                    $.each(item, function (value, item) {

                        var temp = '<tr id="DelChkListRow1' + (rowCount++) + '" data-tr-count="' + (dataCount++) + '" onclick="AccountOf(this)">' +
                            '<td>' + SNo++ + '</td>' +
                      '<td class="tdDiv" style="overflow:auto"><label id="lblCusCode" >' + item.CusCode + '</label><input type="hidden" id="hdnCusCode" value="' + item.CusCode + '"/></td>' +
                      '<td class="tdDiv" style="overflow:auto"><label id="lblCusDesc">' + item.CusDesc + '</label></td>' +
                      '<td class="tdDiv" style="overflow:auto"><label id="lblNIC">' + item.NIC + '</label></td>' +
                      '<td class="tdDiv" style="overflow:auto"><label id="lblAddress">' + item.Address1 + '</label></td>' +
                      '<td class="tdDiv" style="overflow:auto"><label id="lblPhone">' + item.Phone1 + '</label></td>' +
                        '</tr>';

                        $("#AccountOfTable tbody").append(temp);


                    });

                }
            }
        },
        complete: function () {

        },
    });
```

Comment: are you writing this code inside document ready?

Comment: No I have made a separate function on table in modal..
basically I am selecting data from a table in Modal...

Comment: 1st try to do run lines from console what is happening `$("#ddlACof").val(123);$("#ddlACof").change(); ` with any code does it work. i think "ddlACof" id is not available or repeated

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#ddlACof" ).trigger( "change" );
```

Comment: you are not changing the value of $ddlACof as it is commented in your code. maybe thats why it is not being triggered.